# Remove Footer and content footer from page structure from community

Tags: community, customer-community, community-builder, partner-communities, partner-portal

Can we remove footer, content footer section from page structure of perticular community page?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Yes but this will involve some work up-front to make a variation of your theme layout without your footer.

1. First, you will need to create a custom theme layout. If you are using Lightning Web Runtime, follow the [Create Custom Layout Components document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/get_started_layout.htm) to create a layout. Otherwise follow the [Create a Custom Theme Layout Component Trailhead for Aura.](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/communities_theme_layout/create_component?trail_id=customize-your-community)

2. When you make the layout, be sure to *not* include a footer slot.
3. Go to your Experience Site Builder, then Settings > Theme. Under Theme, click "New Theme Layout". Select your new Theme Layout Component and give it an appropriate name like "Footerless".
4. Next, go to the page you want to override, then go to Page Properties > Layout and check the "Override the default theme layout for this page" checkbox. Select your *Footerless* theme.

[image: Editing Page Properties to change the Theme Layout]